# How to use SQL Server Pivot on Multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have the folowing table format/ data which am trying to transpose using the SQL Server Pivot statement. Cant get it despite Googling for the last 24hrs.

This is what I have in the table:

```
---------   ------      -------     -------     -------
Product     Brand       Region1     Region2     Region3
---------   ------      -------     -------     -------
Product A   BrandX      120        1005         7500
Product B   BrandY      522        422          566
Product C   BrandX      455        255          655
```

This is the result I wish to achieve:

```
---------   ------      -------     -------     
Product     Product A   Product B   Product C
---------   ------      -------     -------     
Brand       BrandX      BrandY      BrandX
Region1     120         522         455
Region2     1005        422         255
Region3     7500        566         655
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: is first row in your desired ouput the header? If so, can you please mark header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use unpivot inside a pivot and remember to convert the columns into the same type:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM 
     (SELECT Product, Brand, 
      convert(varchar(6), Region1) as Region1,
      convert(varchar(6), Region2) as Region2,
      convert(varchar(6), Region3) as Region3
      FROM Table1) t1
  UNPIVOT
     (Data FOR Col IN 
        (Brand, Region1, Region2, Region3)
  )AS unpvt
) P
PIVOT
(
  max (Data)
  FOR Product IN
  ( [Product A], [Product B], [Product C] )
) AS pvt
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1fc1b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Same, but a little different version:

```
;with cte as(select Product, 
                    Brand, 
                    cast(Region1 as varchar(100)) Region1,
                    cast(Region2 as varchar(100)) Region2,             
                    cast(Region3 as varchar(100)) Region3
             from t)           
select b as Product, [Product A], [Product B], [Product C]
from cte
unpivot(a for b in([Brand],[Region1],[Region2],[Region3]))u
pivot(max(a) for Product in([Product A],[Product B],[Product C]))p
```

Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c23cfa/3